How to get font path by unicode codepoint on Windows?
Now, I have some unicode char32_t code points that come from a network transfer, and I don't know ahead of time what language it belongs to. Some code points can be rendered using the default fonts provided within the application, but some cannot.
I've extracted the code points that can't be rendered directly into an array, and now I'd like to enumerate the system font paths for each code point in turn that are most suitable for rendering in Windows.
Which Windows api should I use?

It depends what you want to do.
Drawing Text with GDI or DirectWrite
Most of the text rendering functions in WinAPI will handle it for you using font linking and font fallback.
Font Linking:  Windows has lists that group visually compatible fonts.  (At least some of the lists are in the registry.)  So if you had selected a well-known font the normally ships with Windows, say Arial.  If you issue a GDI TextOut call with a string that requires glyphs not available in Arial, the system will look up the list of visually compatible fonts for Arial and check to see whether any of the fonts on that list has the necessary glyphs.  If it does, then GDI works with the system to switch between the fonts as needed to draw the entire string, leaving the selected font as it was when you began made the call.
(Long ago, font linking required COM interfaces provided by Internet Explorer and doing much of the switching work yourself.)
Font Fallback:  If you had selected an unusual font that wasn't known to the font linking system, or if the glyphs necessary were not available in any of the linked fonts, lower levels had a small set of shipped-with-Windows fonts that it would check.  These are hardcoded into Uniscribe (or lower?) and aren't configurable with registry settings.  These are unlikely to be visually similar to the font you had selected.  It's just a last desperate attempt.  If font fallback fails, you'd probably see the Unicode replacement character (often a box).
You might encounter other mechanisms, like font substitution, which tweak font selections for other reasons.
Processing Text Yourself
If you're working at a lower level, you have to do all the work to find appropriate fonts.  Doing it the naïve way can be slow.  Lazy evaluation and caching is essential if you're going to do it a lot.
Windows doesn't (to my knowledge) have an API that let's you query "which font supports this code point or glyph index?"
Instead you have to ask a particular font for the glyphs for a string of text and then check whether it has them all.
If you're using GDI (which provides only partial support for complex scripts), you can call GetGlyphIndicesW with GGI_MARK_NONEXISTING_GLYPHS and then searching the result for 0xFFFF.
If you're using Uniscribe, you can call ScriptShape and then check the resulting list of glyphs to see if any are missing.  (Note that there other steps required before you can call ScriptShape.)
You can enumerate fonts using EnumFonts.  But a typical Windows machine has a lot of fonts installed.  Running through all of them is going to take time.  Also, many of them may have glyphs for the symbols you need.  If you choose a font whose visual style is very different from the font used for the surrounding glyphs, that's going to be jarring.
One thing you can do is implement font-linking yourself.  If the primary font is well known, you'll find a short-ish list of visually compatible fonts to try.
As far as I know, there's no API for getting the font-linking lists other than reading them directly from the registry.  Here's the key:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink

Work through the linked fonts in the order they're given and choose the first one that has what you need.  If you get to the end and you still don't have it, you can then search all fonts on the machine or just punt.
Another approach for trying to find visually compatible fonts involves comparing Panose numbers.  I'm not versed in that, but you can read about it in the Microsoft documentation.
Tips for filtering out fonts that aren't worth checking:

Some fonts appear twice, once with a regular name, and again with prefixed with '@'.  The '@' version is designed for vertical lines of text rather than rows.  Other than that, they almost certainly have the same coverage, so you don't have to check both.

Whenever you load a font, you can query its FONTSIGNATURE and cache it.  One part of the font signature is a bitmask indicating which Unicode subranges the font supports.  If you're looking for a font to support some text in the Arabic code range (for example), and the font you want to check doesn't have the corresponding signature bit set, you can just skip it without loading it and trying to generate glyphs for it.  (Note that, fonts may indicate they support a certain subrange even if they don't support every single codepoint in that subrange.)


There's still some nuance to choosing the best fonts to link.  In many cases, you'll probably have more than one choice.  I suggest:

Choose the smallest number of fonts that lets you handle the entire string.  If you need two glyphs not handled by the primary font, it's usually better to find a font that provides both than to grab each from a different font.

Fonts for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean have largely the same coverage due to Unicode's Han Unification, but they tend to have distinctive visual styles.  If your primary font is designed for Japanese (for example) but it's missing a single glyph needed to render a particular string in Japanese, you probably shouldn't link to a Chinese or Korean font to get just that glyph.  You probably should render the entire string in a single font that has all the necessary glyphs.  (This is based on advice I got from user feedback many years ago.  I'm not an expert on CJK typography.)  In practice, this is not always possible.  You'd have to know the target language of the font and the language of the text to display.



Thanks, I've benefited from your response.
I'm currently using IDWriteFontFallback::MapCharacters to implement this, although it's not perfect.

From your codepoint, IDWriteFontFallback::MapCharacters will give you a IDWriteFont object.
From the IDWriteFont, you can get the font path. I recommand you to see this post to know how to do it.

Thanks, I tried IDWriteFontFallback::MapCharacters and it really seemed to work. There are some minor flaws though.

Could you explain the minor flaws you have? There may be a solution
